# Spring MVC How take the parameter value of a GET HTTP Request in my controller method?

Tags: java, spring, http, parameters, request

In this period I am studing the Spring MVC showcase example (downloadable from STS dasboard) and I have some simple question about the `Request Mapping` examples:

1) In my `home.jsp` page I have this link:

```
        <li>
            <a id="byParameter" class="textLink" href="<c:url value="/mapping/parameter?foo=bar" />">By path, method, and presence of parameter</a>
        </li>
```

As you can see by this link I am doing an HTTP GET Request having a "foo" parameter containing the value: "bar".

This HTTP Request is handled by the following method of the controller class MappingController:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/mapping/parameter", method=RequestMethod.GET, params="foo")
public @ResponseBody String byParameter() {
    return "Mapped by path + method + presence of query parameter! (MappingController)";
}
```

This method manage HTTP Request (only `GET` type) that have a parameter named "foo"

How can I take the value ("bar") of this parameter and put it in a variable inside the code of my by Parameter method?

Answer (score 185, accepted):

As explained in [the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-ann-requestparam), by using an `@RequestParam` annotation:

```
public @ResponseBody String byParameter(@RequestParam("foo") String foo) {
    return "Mapped by path + method + presence of query parameter! (MappingController) - foo = "
           + foo;
}
```

Comment: In case when there are  10 number of parameters, do we have to do this 10 times or there is a better way for thar scenario

Comment: @Count: click the link I gave to the documentation, then scroll up a little until the paragraph "Supported method argument types", and read the part about "Command or form objects"

Answer (score 43):

You could also use a URI template.  If you structured your request into a restful URL Spring could parse the provided value from the url.

**HTML**

```
<li>
    <a id="byParameter" 
       class="textLink" href="<c:url value="/mapping/parameter/bar />">By path, method,and
           presence of parameter</a>
</li>
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/mapping/parameter/{foo}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String byParameter(@PathVariable String foo) {
    //Perform logic with foo
    return "Mapped by path + method + presence of query parameter! (MappingController)";
}
```

[Spring URI Template Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates)