# Spring request param string - jackson

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

I have a spring controller with method

```
@RequestMapping(value="/list", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView getList(NSomeObject someObject)
```

but the query is something like `localhost:8080/list?a=some_value&b=some_value`

How to convert this to java object? Is there any counterpart of json and jackson?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442678/spring-mvc-how-take-the-parameter-value-of-a-get-http-request-in-my-controller-m

Comment: Check this URL  http://www.studytrails.com/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-controller-input.jsp

Answer (score 2):

You should do the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/list", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView getList(@RequestParam("a") String a_value, @RequestParam("b") String b_value, @RequestBody NSomeObject someObject)
```