# Making href (anchor tag) request POST instead of GET as passing the parameter

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, spring-mvc

The issue is that when I am using the below approach, the entire URL is showing up. Maybe because of the GET request if href. I want to avoid this and and I want the POST request.

**index.html**

```html
<a id="ccviewMiniStatementId">View mini statement</a>
```

**nonFinancial.js**

```js
$('#ccviewMiniStatementId').click(function(event) {

    var ccMonthVal=$("#ccMonthId").val();
    var ccYearVal=$("#ccYearId").val();
    var cCRefNumId=$("#cCRefNumId").val();

    var errExpVal = validateCcExpiry();

    if (errExpVal==false)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }

    // I am passing values to my controller and there it is GET 
    //because POST is not supported. I want to make it POST.
    $("#ccviewMiniStatementId").attr("href", "getpdfcreditcard?month="+ccMonthVal+"&year="+ccYearVal+"&cCReferenceNo="+cCRefNumId);
    $("#pdfViewer").submit();           
});
```

My controller **NonFinancial.java**

```java
@RequestMapping(value="/getpdfcreditcard", method=RequestMethod.GET, params = {"month","year","cCReferenceNo"})
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getPDF(@RequestParam(value="month", required = true) String month,
    @RequestParam(value="year", required = true) String year,
    @RequestParam(value="cCReferenceNo", required = true) String cCReferenceNo,
    HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, SQLException {

    logger.debug("month/year/cCReferenceNo: "+month+"/"+year+"/"+cCReferenceNo);
}
```

So I would like: when I am clicking on an anchor tag it should do a POST. How do I do that? I don't want to use a `<form></form>`

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are using jQuery, so it is easy:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var fullLink = $(this).attr('href');
    var splittedLink = fullLink.split("?");
    var href = splittedLink[0];
    var qs = splittedLink[1];

    // convert qs to body
    var splittedQs = qs.split('&');
    var body = {};

    for(var key in splittedQs) {
        var t = splittedQs[key].split('=');
        body[t[0]] = t[1];
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        data: body,
        url: href,
        success: function() { ... }
    });

    return false;  // prevent default
});
```

Comment: if i use ajax then pdf will not be generated from contoller thats why i am not using ajax.

Comment: @RahulKhanna if you don't want Ajax, you can generate the form dynamically and submit it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in HTML to make a `href` use POST. However as @modernator pointed out, you can use JavaScript to listen to the click event and then manually trigger an AJAX request.

Alternatively you could use a form with hidden inputs. In there you can specify the submit method. Example:

```
<form method="post" action="<your-url>">
    <input type="hidden" name="month" value="<month-value>">
    <button type="submit">View Statement</button>
</form>
```

Comment: But i want to pass value as well. How could i do that?

Comment: Via the `type="hidden"` inputs. In my example above the form will submit something akin to `{ month: "<month-value>" }`

Comment: how take values of hidden prompt in controller?

Comment: @RahulKhanna I see that your edited answer specifies that you don't want to use a from. I'm not familiar with spring mvc, but I feel that it could be your controller syntax, because it should support GET requests. After a quick google search I found [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442678/spring-mvc-how-take-the-parameter-value-of-a-get-http-request-in-my-controller-m), maybe it can help you.

Comment: i dont want button , client need hyperlink only i.e. anchor tag.