# Manipulate url parameters Restful API

Tags: rest, api, spring-mvc, restful-url

I just need to know how to manipulate url parameters when someone calls my API with parameters.

```
http://localhost:8100/apis/employee?firstName=john&lastName=Do
```

I want to use these firstName and lastName parameters on my GET method but I don't know how to extract them.

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response getEmployee() {

//Just need to extract the parameters in here so I can use on the logic to return only the ones that meet the requirements. 

}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am using SpringBootApplication on Java

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I am using SpringBootApplication on Java

Comment: Don't know much about Java, maybe [this older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13442732/1397220) helps you out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the annotations shown in your question, you are using **JAX-RS** (probably with Jersey). So use [`@QueryParam`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html):

```java
@GET
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Response getEmployee(@QueryParam("firstName") String firstName, 
                            @QueryParam("lastName") String lastName) {
   ...
}
```

For **Spring MVC** (that also provides REST capabilities), you want to use [`@RequestParam`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html):

```java
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET,
                produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, 
                             MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
public Response getEmployee(@RequestParam("firstName") String firstName, 
                            @RequestParam("lastName") String lastName) {
   ...
}
```

---

Both JAX-RS (with Jersey) and Spring MVC can be used with Spring Boot. See the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html) for details.

Also refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42955575/1426227) for details on the differences between Spring MVC and JAX-RS.

Comment: Yes that is correct, I am using JAX-RS. I have a question. If I want to pull an employee by ID, I can use employeeRepository.findOne() where employeeRepository is an interface extending PagingAndSortingRepository. How about if I want to select an employee based on firstName or lastName what do I do? Do I implement my method on employeeRepository interface?? I am asking just because I don't want to reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: @DoArNa That's out of the scope for your current question, so you should consider asking a new one. However, it would be something like `Employee findByFirstNameIgnoreCaseAndLastNameIgnoreCase(String firstName, String lastName)`.

Comment: It seems it is not recognizing the firstName and lastName on "@QueryParam". Do I have to add any annotation "@Path" or something like that? If so, how would that look like?

Answer (score 0):

`@RequestParam` is what you are looking for

```
public Response getEmployee(@RequestParam("firstName") String firstName, @RequestParam("lastName") String lastName) {
...
}
```

Comment: The OP is using Spring Boot but `@GET` and `@Produces` belong to JAX-RS (which can be used with Spring). So the correct annotation is `@QueryParam` and not `@RequestParam`. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48154062/1426227) for further details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@RequestParam` in your controller method to access the query parameters. e.g.

```
public Response getEmployee(@RequestParam("firstName") String firstName, @RequestParam("lastName") String lastName)
```

Comment: The OP is using Spring Boot but `@GET` and `@Produces` belong to JAX-RS (which can be used with Spring). So the correct annotation is `@QueryParam` and not `@RequestParam`. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48154062/1426227) for further details.